# Water flow under pressure of gravity

Tags: fluid-mechanics

is it possible to calculate the flow of water out of a pipe where gravity is the only force acting upon the water and therefore generating the flow. The pipe diameter is X and there is minimal fall (say 6 inches?).

The real life scenario here is that I am trying to calculate the flow of water out of a washing machine waste when the filter plug is removed at the bottom?

Comment: It would be quite handy if you could provide a sketch of your scenario.

Comment: Sorry Andrew... not sure how to attach a sketch to a comment? Any ideas??

Comment: You could edit your question and add a scan or you can provide a link of the uploaded file in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

The Bernoulli equation will give you a pretty good estimate.  It says that:
$$ P_{1} + \frac{1}{2}\rho v_{1}^{2} + \rho g h_{1} = P_{2} + \frac{1}{2}\rho v_{2}^{2} + \rho g h_{2} $$
You pick 2 points in a flow (1 and 2).  In this case, you can ignore the pressure terms, $P$, and focus on velocity, $v$, height, $h$, and gravitational acceleration, $g$. 
In this case, you can use the free surface of the water in the machine as point 1, meaning that  $P_{1} = v _{1} = 0$, $h_{1}= 0.15 m$, then point 2 is at the outlet of your pipe, and $P_{2} = h_{2} = 0$.  Then: $$ v_{2} = \sqrt{2gh_{1}} $$  gravitational acceleration is $9.81m/s^2$.
If you want to add a (probably small) degree of accuracy to your calculations , the so-called head-loss calculations are useful.  You can use this calculator:
https://apps.engineeringtoolbox.com/head-loss-water-pipe-a_15.html

Which will give you a pressure loss in kPa, and velocity loss in m/s.  You can adjust your prediction as:
$$ v_{adjusted} = v_{2} - v_{loss} $$
so your average flow velocity will 
You'll notice, though, that you need to know the flow rate:$$Q_{2} = v_{2}\pi r_{pipe}^{2}$$
before you can calculate the head loss.

Comment: Hey EMiller, Thanks for your advice. Much appreciated. However would you mind elaborating a little more.

Comment: How do I know what the velocity is?

Comment: Is there a standard for gravitational acceleration?

Comment: Where do I add the diameter of the pipe as surely this will make a difference?

Comment: @David C Bradley , I've edited my answer.  hopefully it's more clear.  The pipe diameter will play a role in head loss, but mostly it's used to calculate the cross-sectional area of the pipe, so that the flow rate can be calculated from the velocity.

Comment: Thanks for the additional notes EMIller. Much appreciated √